# Cannot play local audio embedded in handsontable within rmarkdown Shiny app

Tags: html, shiny, r-markdown, handsontable, rhandsontable

The following rmarkdown creates a Shiny document containing a handsontable with links to wav files that can be played within a browser (use Chrome). The first link in the table points to an external wav file http://www.nch.com.au/acm/11k16bitpcm.wav, the second link points to the same file located in the `www` folder relative to the rmarkdown. The first link works, the second does not. According to various articles I have found online, the `www` folder is the correct place for such external content and in fact, if I place `png` files there I can use the `img()` function within the rmarkdown to get Shiny to correctly display the image.

````
---
title: "Playing audio in handsontable"
date: "18 August 2016"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
library(rhandsontable)
library(dplyr)
links = c('<audio controls preload="none" type="audio/wav" src="http://www.nch.com.au/acm/11k16bitpcm.wav" </audio>',
'<audio controls preload="none" type="audio/wav" src="www/11k16bitpcm.wav" </audio>')
toDisplay = data.frame(Listen = links)
```

The first entry in this table refers to an external WAV file <http://www.nch.com.au/acm/11k16bitpcm.wav> and can be played in a browser. The second entry refers to the same file called `11k16bitpcm.wav` located in the folder `www` relative to the markdown but cannot be played. As a check, if the file can be seen from the markdown, the following will be TRUE: `r file.exists("www/11k16bitpcm.wav")`.

```{r tabsets, echo=FALSE}
renderRHandsontable({
  rhandsontable(toDisplay, readOnly = TRUE, allowedTags = "<em><b><strong><a><big><audio>", rowHeaders = TRUE) %>%
  hot_cols(columnSorting = T) %>%
  hot_col(1, renderer = "html") %>%
  hot_col(1, renderer = htmlwidgets::JS("safeHtmlRenderer"))
})
```
````

Does anyone have any tips to help me get the second link working and correctly serving audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function addResourcePath within the shiny package is the answer.

Here is the code with the appropriate call.

````
---
title: "Playing audio in handsontable"
date: "18 August 2016"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
library(rhandsontable)
library(dplyr)
links = c('<audio controls preload="none" type="audio/wav" src="http://www.nch.com.au/acm/11k16bitpcm.wav" </audio>',
'<audio controls preload="none" type="audio/wav" src="www/11k16bitpcm.wav" </audio>')
toDisplay = data.frame(Listen = links)
# this declares a path containing the resource
addResourcePath("www", "www")
```

The first entry in this table refers to an external WAV file <http://www.nch.com.au/acm/11k16bitpcm.wav> and can be played in a browser. The second entry refers to the same file called `11k16bitpcm.wav` located in the folder `www` relative to the markdown but cannot be played unless a call to `shiny::addResourcePath()` is made. As a check, if the file can be seen from the markdown, the following will be TRUE: `r file.exists("www/11k16bitpcm.wav")`.

```{r tabsets, echo=FALSE}
renderRHandsontable({
  rhandsontable(toDisplay, readOnly = TRUE, allowedTags = "<em><b><strong><a><big><audio>", rowHeaders = TRUE) %>%
  hot_cols(columnSorting = T) %>%
  hot_col(1, renderer = "html") %>%
  hot_col(1, renderer = htmlwidgets::JS("safeHtmlRenderer"))
})
```
````